# Daloradius showing user as offline

Tags: freeradius

I have a freeradius w/ daloradius server(linuxmint 21) set up, and everything appears to be working as expected, except for accounting, because even when I connect as a user to the wifi (with EAP method type PWD), daloradius will report the user as offline, and also tracks no network activity, even though I'm able to browse the internet normally. I've enabled `sql` in the `accounting{}` section in the sites-enabled/default file but still no change.

Any ideas on anything I might have missed?